# Can you use nginx reverse proxy to docker containers without exposing any ports?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I'd like to know if it's possible to use nginx with docker compose as an api gateway / reverse proxy / ssl termination point without exposing any ports on the containers behind it. I.e. I want to use only the intranet created by docker compose when the containers are linked to communicate past nginx. Ideally the only publicly accessible port will be port 443 (ssl) on nginx. Is this doable? Or do I have to expose ports on my containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is doable.

Just define your application in one container and nginx in another container, both in the same docker-compose.yml. Link them. And only expose the 443 port in nginx container.

docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    links:
        - node1:node1
        - node2:node2
        - node3:node3
    ports:
        - "443:443"
node1:
    build: ./node
node2:
    build: ./node
node3:
    build: ./node
```

More info: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/

Regards

Comment: Hey Carlos, thanks for the quick response. In this scenario, what would the nginx.conf file look like? How would I proxy traffic to nodes 1, 2, and 3 upstream without host:port?

Comment: :-S I only know about docker conectivity. I had configured this once between nginx and docker registry but someone else did the nginx configuration. I can recommend this guide: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/ it is a complete example of what you are looking for.

Comment: If you put a port without the colon, is that still exposed? I've seen that guide before and was wondering if those were internal or external ports

Comment: Yes it is exposed via a random number. Do not put those ports in your docker-compose file, just the nginx one.

Comment: @LoganShire if you follow this setup, the nodes will be available in the nginx container by host name. You should be able to just route to `node1` and docker will resolve it to the right place.

Comment: @R0MANARMY can I proxy_pass traffic with a given path prefix to a given node by its host name? E.g. If I have a node called 'users' which hosts my users service, can I proxy traffic to mydomain.com/users/* to my users container without exposing any ports on users to the outside world?

Comment: I believe so, you'll at least be able to resolve the hostname `users` to the correct container from inside the nginx container. Should be a pretty quick test to try it out.