# docker-compose : How can I isolate a docker container from "outside" (jenkins container + nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: networking, docker-compose

As a training mockup I am trying to setup a jenkins instance behind an nginx reverse proxy ensuring also https.
So I create one container for nginx and one for jenkins. I have succeded, including the nginx configuration with (auto-signed) certificates.
I can reach the jenkins instance using https and the nginx container ip from my machine.
But my final goal is to completely isolate the jenkins container so that it cannot be reached at all from "outside". And this is not achieved.
The default port declared in the official image being 8080, I can still reach the jenkins instance with the jenkins container IP and the port 8080.

I'd made a first setup through an ansible playbook using docker container and it worked well.
But, I cannot obtain the same behavior with docker-compose.
Here is the docker-compose file I wrote.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  revproxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    depends_on:
      - jenkins_ci
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "90:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /home/vagrant/dockerResources/etc/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /home/vagrant/dockerResources/etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse_proxy.conf
  jenkins_ci:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    networks:
      - proxy
networks:
  proxy:
    name: revProxy
    internal: yes
```

When inspecting the jenkins_ci container, I can find its IP and direct my browser to this IP with port 8080. That's I don't want to be able to do. I would like the jenkins container to be reachable only through nginx reverse proxy address.

If someone could give me a hint.

Comment: you can not change that , the isolation will be to use firewall that allow only the nginx ports , I do not aware of another possible way

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem.
Knowing that the jenkins image default exposed port is 8080, I have set :

```
ports:
  - "8080"
```

on the jenkins_ci service definition in the docker-compose file.

Now, I can see that there is no more IP address for jenkins_ci container. Nevertheless, it remains accessible from another container (here, the nginx one) thanks to the service name (so jenkins_ci).

I found the solution within this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144250/can-you-use-nginx-reverse-proxy-to-docker-containers-without-exposing-any-ports).

Unfortunaltely, declaring the exposed port number without its public counterpart to hide the exposed port (and thus the IP if no port at all are publicly exposed) is not recall in the [docker-compose port syntax section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).